$S$ is the circumcircle of $∆ABC$ and $S_A, S_B, S_C$ are the reflections of $S$ across $BC, CA, AB$, respectively. Prove that $S_A, S_B, S_C$ concur.
Question:
Let $S$ be the circumcircle of $∆ABC$, and $S_A, S_B, S_C$ are the reflections of $S$ across $BC, CA, AB$, respectively. Prove that $S_A, S_B, S_C$ intersect at a common point by identifying this point of intersection.
My Solution:
My solution purely relied on complex coordinate geometry (vectors). WLOG, suppose that $S$ is the unit circle centered at the origin of the Argand plane.

$\color{blue} S$ is the circle in blue with center $\color{blue}{O(0, 0)}$ while $\color{green}{S_A, S_B, S_C}$ are the circles in green with centers $\color{green}{X, Y, Z}$, respectively. $\color{red}{D, E, F}$ are the points about which $O$ is reflected across $BC, CA, AB$.
Since $d = \frac{b + c}{2}$, it implies that $x = 2d = b + c$. As a result, $B, C$ lie on $S_A$ because $|x - b| = |c| = 1$ and $|x - c| = |b| = 1$. Translating $X$ to the origin ($S_A \mapsto S$) means $A$ lies on $S_A'$. Thus, translating $S_A' = S$ back to $S_A$ suggests $a \mapsto a + b + c = h$, i.e., $A \mapsto H$, where $H$ is the orthocenter of $∆ABC$.
Using the same procedure, it can be shown that $H$ lies on all three — $S_A, S_B, S_C$. Therefore, $S_A, S_B, S_C$ intersect at a common point (marked $\color{purple}P$). More specifically, $P = H$. $\blacksquare$
While this a valid proof, I would be really interested in a synthetic proof as I tried to formulate a synthetic proof for two days before ultimately resorting to a complex geometry proof...

Produce altitude $AH$ to meet circumcircle $S$ at $O'$ and let $O$ be the reflection of $O'$ about $BC$. We have
(intersecting chords theorem):
$$
AH\cdot O'H=BH\cdot CH
\ \implies\ 
AH\cdot OH=BH\cdot CH
\ \implies\ 
AH:CH=BH:OH.
$$
The last equality implies that triangles $ACH$ and $OBH$ are similar
and in particular $\angle CAH=\angle OBH$.
Produce now $BO$ to meet $AC$ at $K$: triangles $AOK$ and $BOH$ have then the same angles, in particular $\angle AKO=90°$. Hence $O$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$.
It follows that $S_A$ passes through the orthocenter $O$ of $ABC$ and, by the same reasoning, so do $S_B$ and $S_C$.

